# Transaction parsing - Satoshi value

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, output

how exactly is the satoshi value in a raw transaction calculated to decimal? Because on blockchain.info, I cannot figure out how they parse the raw transaction from that value to the JSON result. I thought it would be just a hex to decimal parsing, but I cannot get the same results. Neither I understand it in here, how you get to 49.99990000 BTC (from https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/transactions.html):[image]

Sorry if it's a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount is encoded as a little endian signed 64 bits integer.

Here is how you would decode your sample in Python:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex("f0ca052a01000000"), "little")
4999990000
```